# CSS vary div between two width values

Tags: html, css

I am trying style a div so that its width decreases after a certain point wrt to the width of the viewport.

Here is my code:

```
<div data-category="budget" class="hotels-block active ">
    <img src="images/budget1.jpg">
    <div class="info-block">
       <h2>BUDGET HOTEL 1</h2>
       <p>fist line, second line, USA, third line comes over here</p>
       <hr/>
       <a href="#book" class="book-now">BOOK NOW</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.hotels-block {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.hotels-block img {
    float:left;
}

.info-block {
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #62bcb1;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-bottom: -9999px;
    padding-bottom: 9999px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1050px)
{
    .info-block
    {
    width: 30%;
    }
}
```

I want the width of the `.info-block` div to reduce until the viewport width hits 961px. 
Currently, `.info-block` shrinks until 977px and then falls to the next line.

How do I prevent `.info-block` from going to the next line? No JS/JQuery please.

Comment: Take a look at the [min-width][1] property in CSS, it is used to set the minimum width of a given element. So in your case that would be 977px. 


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width

Comment: @Muggles put that in an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you want to use `min-width` and `max-width` properties? usually as absolutes and then set the standard width to a percentage. Also set the width in the media query to `!important` to supersede the pre-set arrangement.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1050px)
{
    .info-block
    {
min-width:200px;
    width: 30% !important;
max-width:400px;
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I thought min-width was used as a work around in cases involving inner content of a div